# Cakephp2 https redirects on AWS ECS

Tags: php, https, amazon-ecs, cakephp-2.0

I have this old cakephp2 application that I'm deploying it to AWS ECS.
However, it needs to redirect all the requests to https.
I have updated the `.htaccess` as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status
   RewriteBase /

   RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
   RewriteRule !/status https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
   RewriteRule ^$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/users/login [R,L]

   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I would expect that all requests were being redirect to https but there is one that is still not being correctly redirected. From the login page, when clicking login, it should redirect the user to `https://%{SERVER_NAME}/tests/users` however when making requests to that url `https://%{SERVER_NAME}/tests/users` it keeps redirecting the request to (http) `http://%{SERVER_NAME}/users/login`. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: You can enable [logging](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging) to see what mod_rewrite is doing. It seems likely there is another redirect within the CakePHP2 app. If the login form is posting to http, the redirect (default 302 - temporarily moved) will not result in the post body being resent, so the login will fail.

Comment: Thanks @user1191247 it looks like it's not related to the redirection rules. I have been testing and even without redirection when requesting from 'https://%{SERVER_NAME}/tests/users' it was always redirecting to 'http://%{SERVER_NAME}/users/login' somehow. Not sure were this redirection may be happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
```

in one of your rewrite conditions suggests you might be using an ELB (or similar) to terminate SSL and forward requests to your web servers unencrypted.

CakePHP 2 relies on the `HTTPS` variable being set by the web server to indicate that the request was encrypted (check `env` function in lib/Cake/basics.php or search `'HTTPS'` in lib/Cake/bootstrap.php). You can use [`SetEnvIf`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_setenvif.html) to add the variable based on the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto "https" HTTPS=on
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue. I have tried to add it before on the Appcontroller beforefilter() function '$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';' but it didn't work

Comment: Glad it solved your issue.